# Is there a way to distinguish two HTTP/SSL requests coming from different sources in Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, http

My use case requires doing separate handling for each source. Parsing the packet is not possible due to performance issues.

Comment: *"...separate handling for each source"* is a very unspecific requirement but  [mod_rewrite based on ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073852/mod-rewrite-based-on-ip) might give you an idea how to implement what you want to do.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I will clear the requirement. So I have two different pieces of software which coincidentally use the exact same REST API interface. The only difference is the source from where the API call has originated.

Comment: Still not sufficient information. But if Apache is used as reverse proxy for different backend the link I've included in the comment should help. See also [Apache reverse proxy forwarding different source IP ranges to different destination URLs](https://serverfault.com/questions/557478/apache-reverse-proxy-forwarding-different-source-ip-ranges-to-different-destinat).